# How to do "if" in model's array each in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to ask in models for .each array if label or key exists if not, skip it or put "0" ??

For example, I have this which works now from previous questions and I figured out the problem but I need to do an "if story["something"]["something"] doesn't exists, skip it leave it NIL or put 0" ... same thing for a single one, "if story["something"} doesn't exists, skip it leave it NIL or 0"

Here's the update and live code...

in my whatever model, I've got;

```
 fbstory = User.current.facebook.get_connection("me", "home")
```

which brings back this

```
 => {"id"=>"23648815198_10152713082585199", "from"=>{"category"=>"Sports team", "category_list"=>[{"id"=>"10101672249695001", "name"=>"Sports Team"}], "name"=>"Toronto Maple Leafs", "id"=>"23648815198"}, "to"=>{"data"=>[{"category"=>"Sports league", "name"=>"NHL", "id"=>"61652252465"}]}, "message"=>"From the NHL: David Clarkson looks for a fresh start as he begins his second season with the Blue and White.\n\nRead the full story here: http://is.gd/RfnAuS", "message_tags"=>{"9"=>[{"id"=>"61652252465", "name"=>"NHL", "type"=>"page", "offset"=>9, "length"=>3}]}, "picture"=>"https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCL3fZFMGEP2dJd&w=158&h=158&url=http%3A%2F%2F2.cdn.nhle.com%2Fmapleleafs%2Fimages%2Fupload%2F2013%2F11%2Fclarkson620nov8.jpg", "link"=>"http://mapleleafs.nhl.com/club/news.htm?id=732603", "name"=>"David Clarkson Eager To Turn It Around", "caption"=>"mapleleafs.nhl.com", "description"=>"Right wing David Clarkson did not perform well in his first season with the Toronto Maple Leafs, but he's eager to turn things around in 2014-15.", "icon"=>"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y5/r/sXJx2UP7quc.png", "actions"=>[{"name"=>"Comment", "link"=>"https://www.facebook.com/23648815198/posts/10152713082585199"}, {"name"=>"Like", "link"=>"https://www.facebook.com/23648815198/posts/10152713082585199"}], "privacy"=>{"value"=>""}, "type"=>"link", "status_type"=>"shared_story", "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:15:01+0000", "updated_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:16:27+0000", "shares"=>{"count"=>17}, "likes"=>{"data"=>[{"id"=>"10152787182894993", "name"=>"Tracy Walker-Caverson"}, {"id"=>"10152756972054137", "name"=>"Taylor Kathleen"}, {"id"=>"10203569785459900", "name"=>"Robin Eldridge"}, {"id"=>"10152775032829490", "name"=>"Kyle Vachon"}, {"id"=>"10154612226985142", "name"=>"Adam Franks"}, {"id"=>"10152678166165399", "name"=>"Paul G Simons"}, {"id"=>"10152742630043545", "name"=>"Holly Chuback"}, {"id"=>"10201889545160252", "name"=>"Christopher Groeber"}, {"id"=>"302852516569062", "name"=>"Jysha JC"}, {"id"=>"840799135960446", "name"=>"William Deshotel"}, {"id"=>"10154660601695611", "name"=>"Josh Dowden"}, {"id"=>"10152434222598348", "name"=>"Rita Lynn Holland"}, {"id"=>"10152324234392274", "name"=>"Chris Czerny Worton"}, {"id"=>"1499650110286787", "name"=>"Michael Ferguson"}, {"id"=>"10152714836666061", "name"=>"Dean Capstick"}, {"id"=>"375799292570584", "name"=>"Tyler Henry"}, {"id"=>"10152493549483541", "name"=>"Melanie Joy"}, {"id"=>"10153264278549852", "name"=>"Henry Paul Marsh"}, {"id"=>"1481650518753510", "name"=>"Diana Allen"}, {"id"=>"10152462988960369", "name"=>"Matt Calvert"}, {"id"=>"10153285403804782", "name"=>"John George"}, {"id"=>"10152778781075799", "name"=>"Joella Marano"}, {"id"=>"10154644689390263", "name"=>"Dany Yeah Yeah"}, {"id"=>"347021735465740", "name"=>"Yeasha Lee"}, {"id"=>"10152835563632625", "name"=>"Mike Mazzei"}], "paging"=>{"cursors"=>{"after"=>"MTAxNTI4MzU1NjM2MzI2MjU=", "before"=>"MTAxNTI3ODcxODI4OTQ5OTM="}, "next"=>"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/23648815198_10152713082585199/likes?access_token=CAAKErEce2PkBAIu2lALgBgZC3IDiZBzjDny8J0eniB4PQNHaTDpzKhlZAo51e7nE3U6qdOvE5qOmLlfOOZCXZAmeyMb2qo9sOlcgrBZCL3Pin5efZBoPFX2R7eeQPj9Uyrs4dZAMLh1MF7chYWln4ZAhM7kU92sU3AS3y9C7PY0WOCsT4Khc05K13juUMqV6cGc9pYYdpSmumCxyXUmNXHnaX&limit=25&after=MTAxNTI4MzU1NjM2MzI2MjU%3D"}}, "comments"=>{"data"=>[{"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713145555199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152790777668987", "name"=>"Lucas Neilson"}, "message"=>"if not he will protect the water bottle like a champion.", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:15:51+0000", "like_count"=>19, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713146310199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152496303744302", "name"=>"Daniel Gertler"}, "message"=>"Let me put it this way, even if Clarkson plays his best he's still getting over paid for far too long.", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:16:27+0000", "like_count"=>15, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713149750199", "from"=>{"id"=>"399195896901819", "name"=>"Jessica Smith"}, "message"=>"Not his fault he was offered the kind of money he was.  He had a bad season last year.  I hope he learns from some of the mistakes he made and has a great season.  He's a hometown guy, let's support him.  Go Leafs Go!", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:19:16+0000", "like_count"=>11, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713170740199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10100208958447874", "name"=>"Jamie Gilbert"}, "message"=>"Package Clarkson and Pheneuf up and send them to Montreal for a bag of pucks.", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:34:15+0000", "like_count"=>4, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713149990199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152305195902234", "name"=>"Glen Boris"}, "message"=>"Maybe he should stop fighting in f'n preseason", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:19:31+0000", "like_count"=>3, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713146375199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10154660368805434", "name"=>"Jordan Addy"}, "message"=>"Last year was a fluke with suspensions and injuries. Clarkson will bounce back ! 15 goals isn't out of the question from a guy like him ", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:16:29+0000", "like_count"=>6, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713220755199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152484680833271", "name"=>"Ben Martin"}, "message"=>"Believe it when I see it", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:07:02+0000", "like_count"=>2, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713173640199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152446658539895", "name"=>"Malcolm Stark"}, "message"=>"All the best David, hope you can turn it around!!", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:36:12+0000", "like_count"=>2, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713201220199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152800455743092", "name"=>"Kelly Olohan"}, "message"=>"They got him for PP help in front of the net.  Wasn't used in that capacity.  I don't want JVR having to duck when Princess fires those unguided missiles head high.  He'll be better if Carlyle uses him properly.", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:55:58+0000", "like_count"=>1, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713172500199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10204877947046545", "name"=>"Merv McCreight"}, "message"=>"He's not gonna do sh*t! He'll go down in Leafs history as the worst signing that's how Clarkson will be remembered. Even if the Leafs wanted to trade him no one will take on that outrageous contract they gave him, it will be a matter of time when they buy him out.", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:35:29+0000", "like_count"=>1, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713168665199", "from"=>{"id"=>"861347077239287", "name"=>"Doug Crewe"}, "message"=>"you don't have to fight every one david...get your game back first....", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:32:43+0000", "like_count"=>1, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713162890199", "from"=>{"id"=>"803808686308081", "name"=>"Shane Douglas Slaney"}, "message"=>"Shits waste of money like dion", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:29:20+0000", "like_count"=>1, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713157765199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152303116686394", "name"=>"Greg Lemon"}, "message"=>"He won't do anything different. He STINKS", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:25:00+0000", "like_count"=>1, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713153080199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10154623863695471", "name"=>"Matt Ormrod"}, "message"=>"Eager < Able", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:21:48+0000", "like_count"=>1, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713252205199", "from"=>{"id"=>"735650709839383", "name"=>"Lelik Bolik"}, "message"=>"He is great replacement for Grabo Leafs dumped to make a room\n What a second......", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:26:31+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713241195199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10205162126231921", "name"=>"Duncan McFarlane"}, "message"=>"Matt Bridgeland", "message_tags"=>[{"id"=>"10152704839697829", "name"=>"Matt Bridgeland", "type"=>"user", "offset"=>0, "length"=>15}], "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:20:48+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713240700199", "from"=>{"id"=>"305733679628672", "name"=>"Brian Coville"}, "message"=>"Cmon leafs let's go", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:20:20+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713240550199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152749037064134", "name"=>"Angelo Peroff"}, "message"=>"Has now surpassed the Mike Craig signing as the worst ever by the Leafs.", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:20:11+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713237260199", "from"=>{"id"=>"785791571459178", "name"=>"Max Carbone"}, "message"=>"Andrew Gabriele", "message_tags"=>[{"id"=>"723613634399257", "name"=>"Andrew Gabriele", "type"=>"user", "offset"=>0, "length"=>15}], "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:18:04+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713236160199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10154682695180068", "name"=>"Garrett Michael Belisle"}, "message"=>"Get rid of this clown", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:17:31+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713233040199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152872862792189", "name"=>"Zachary J. Bautista"}, "message"=>"yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah.....", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:15:25+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713228195199", "from"=>{"id"=>"1533228070240049", "name"=>"Tanner Hildebrandt"}, "message"=>"Clarkson can do whatever he wants, he will never be worth the 7 million he's gettin this year. What a joke", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:11:53+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713213730199", "from"=>{"id"=>"1534182693479965", "name"=>"Denis Maurice"}, "message"=>"TRADE", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:03:20+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713213665199", "from"=>{"id"=>"10152753314776052", "name"=>"Bruno Lacaria"}, "message"=>"I see no hope with this project", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T14:03:18+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}, {"id"=>"10152713082585199_10152713207465199", "from"=>{"id"=>"387959471353097", "name"=>"William Dupuis"}, "message"=>"We look for it too David", "can_remove"=>false, "created_time"=>"2014-10-02T13:59:31+0000", "like_count"=>0, "user_likes"=>false}], "paging"=>{"cursors"=>{"after"=>"MzI=", "before"=>"NTg="}, "next"=>"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/23648815198_10152713082585199/comments?access_token=CAAKErEce2PkBAIu2lALgBgZC3IDiZBzjDny8J0eniB4PQNHaTDpzKhlZAo51e7nE3U6qdOvE5qOmLlfOOZCXZAmeyMb2qo9sOlcgrBZCL3Pin5efZBoPFX2R7eeQPj9Uyrs4dZAMLh1MF7chYWln4ZAhM7kU92sU3AS3y9C7PY0WOCsT4Khc05K13juUMqV6cGc9pYYdpSmumCxyXUmNXHnaX&limit=25&after=MzI%3D"}}}
```

Koala Gem work with Facebook API and the above is returned.. however I kept getting the 'undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass' error doing this below;

```
 fbstory.each do |story|
    User.current.new_fbtimeline_stories.create({
      fb_id: story["id"], 
      fb_shares: story["share"]["count"], 
    })
 end
```

I kept getting the `undefined method`[]`for nil:NilClass` because I've noticed that ["share"]["count"] or ["share"] for that matter, sometimes doesn't exists at all.. there's nothing, so I'm pretty much looking for ["share"] in the array but its not there.. and some do have it...

So I'm looking for a way to say that "if ["share"] or ["share"]["count"] does exists save the value... and if not, skip it or put 0 ...

Hope that makes it a better explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. The second is close but `unless` is a Ruby keyword and belongs outside the `create` call. It's also almost completely illegible--why not write it in an easy-to-read way first?

Comment: @DaveNewton Let me update the above and give a live example...which I'm sure might help anyone else running into this problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton there ya go :) hope it explains better what I'm getting at... Thanks!

Comment: I just figured I could do `if story.has_key?("shares")` before the `User.current.new_fbtimeline_stories.create` but that just skips the entire story if it doesn't... I'd like to make it so that if "shares" doesn't exists, it still puts a value in that column of "0"..

Comment: Wait... did you ask a question about accessing sub-hashes yesterday? In any case, you can do something like `try` or my preference, the andand gem, e.g., `store.fetch["share"].andand.fetch["count"].presence` or whatever you need the value to be.

Comment: yes I did and its been a nightmare to figure a solution or workaround..  :) Thanks for helping yesterday... I think I've figured something out here, going to post it as an answer.. not sure if its great logic... but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went and figured since I can do `unless?` or `exists?` or even `if` outside of create why not and ask that before the create action like so;

```
if story.has_key?("shares")
   shares_count = story["shares"]["count"].to_i
else
   shares_count = "0"
end

#then we would go and just continue the create action;

User.current.model.create({
   story_id: story["id"],
   story_shares: shares_count
})
```

probably a dirty way and maybe the long way of doing but it works so far and I hope it gives a better idea to everyone else.

Comment: It doesn't cover the case when there's no `"count"` though. This may be okay, just a potential failure mode. I'd also encapsulate that logic into its own method, basically `def shares_count; story.has_key?("shares") ? story["shares"]["count"].to_i : 0; end`

Comment: @DaveNewton that's much easier - Thank you! .. is there something that I can do story.has_key?('shares') ? story["shares"]["count"].to_i : story["shares"]... does `:` mean else or elseif ?? what would else be if not

Comment: It's a ternary expression, the `:` is more or less the `else` part of an if statement. You can use whatever you want for the values.

Comment: how about if I'm looking for a sub key... is that doable still? I've tried `story.has_key?("shares")("count")` sort of setup but no go on that end.

Comment: You still have to call `has_key?` on the hash returning from the first `has_key?` etc.

Comment: like `story.has_key?('shares') story.has_key?('count')` ??

Comment: No, you're calling `has_key?` on `story` both times--you want to call `has_key?` on the *results* of the *first* `has_key?` call, e.g., `story.has_key?('shares').has_key?('count')`. But that can also be handled by `andand` if you only care about the value or a nil, e.g., `story.fetch('shares').andand.fetch('count')`. Play around with it from the REPL (`rails console`) to get a feel for it.

Comment: `story.fetch('shares').fetch('count')` actually works :) however, if its not there the key 'shares' it just returns an error rather then a value of nil or 0.

Comment: Right, that's different than "working", and what the code I provided (more or less) solves.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution but you could do something like:

```ruby
fbstory.each do |story|
   User.current.new_fbtimeline_stories.create({
     fb_id: story["id"], 
     fb_shares: story.fetch("share", {}).fetch("count", 0), 
   })
end
```